# Convert string to date in SQLServer

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, datetime, ssms

I have the following strings in a table

`SEP 21 2009` and `OCT 7 2009`

Is there any way to convert them to a date format in SQL ? I want to check them as date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `CONVERT()` or `CAST()`

**Using** `CONVERT()`:

```
CONVERT ( data_type [ ( length ) ] , expression [ , style ] )
```

Eg:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,'2014/10/15 11:27:06 PM',20)
```

See example of `CONVERT()` in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/30994)

**Using** `CAST()`:

```
CAST ( expression AS data_type [ (length)])
```

Eg:

```
SELECT CAST('MAR 2 1991' as date) as DateValue
SELECT CAST('2013-04-16' AS datetime) AS DateValue
```

See example of `CAST()` in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/30992).

Read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).

Comment: when I try the cast I get the following error :Type DATE is not a defined system type.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you could use `CONVERT(DATETIME,inputdate) AS inputdate`

for more datetime formats you could visit [1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

Comment: i get this error:Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string.

Comment: I saw that before , I have the values in the table, what I want to do is just to directly select from it , I try to use SELECT Cast(DD as date) and SELECT CAST(DD as datetime) and SELECT Convert(DateTime,DD)

Answer (score 0):

You can use CONVERT or CAST. Please check the documentation online.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @a varchar(20)
set @a='SEP 21 2009'

select cast(@a as date)
```

### [SEE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/15580)

Answer (score 0):

You can use CONVERT or CAST. 
More information here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174450.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
select date_col, cast(date_col as date) as dt
from date_tab
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/94f97/2)

Comment: Note that the user asked for SQL Server 2008.. (I checked - they are both the same results)